# validation on dropdown in javascript

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

i have dropdown named po_no with same id which is coming from ajax file

in po_no getting two values in the format of 1025*3

when i put validation on that dropdown in javascript i write this code

```
if(document.getElementById('po_no').value=="")
  {
 alert("Choose Purchase Order Number");
 return false;
  }
```

but this code does not work plz give me ideas

Comment: You will probably need to submit some actual code for anyone to give you a meaningful response.

Answer (score 0):

Does your JavaScript run *after* "po_no" is added to the DOM?  If it runs before, then "document.getElementById('po_no')" will return null.

Answer (score 0):

try these

```
var selObj = document.getElementById('selSeaShells');
```

if(selObj.options[selIndex].value=="")
{
alert("sadAS");
}

REFER

http://www.mredkj.com/tutorials/tutorial002.html